# For an $R$-module $M$, and an ideal $I$ of $R$, does $IM=M$ imply $I=R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Let $M$ be an $R$-module and $I\subseteq R$ an ideal. In Nakayama's Lemma and in a number of situations we have the condition $IM=M$. I was wondering if this automatically implies $I=R$ or $M=0$, or if there are any counter-examples?

Obviously $I \nsubseteq J$ should hold with $J$ the Jacobson-radical of $R$, since otherwise we have $M=0$. I was unable to come up with anything, but maybe that is because I am not using any complicated enough rings (non-noetherian etc.). Can anyone provide any counter examples?

EDIT: I am asking this because I need to show $IM=M$ in an exercise, and I am trying to get a better understanding of what this condition means for $I$.

Comment: What if $M=\{0\}$? What did you try to do?

Comment: No. Consider two nontrivial ideals $J,I$ such that $J+I=R$, and $M=R/J$, then $IM=M$.

Comment: I updated my question. @Mindlack thank you for the counter example.

Comment: A specific counterexample is to take $R = \Bbb{Z}$, $M = \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$ and $I = 3\Bbb{Z}$, so $R$ doesn't have to be at all exotic. (This falls under @Mindlack's more general description - I'm a slower typist $\ddot{\smile}$.)

Comment: Consider any ring with a nontrivial idempotent ideal $I^2=I$ and let $I=M$.

Comment: For example, $I=\{(0,0),(1,0)\}$ in the ring $F_2\times F_2$ where $F_2$ is the field of two elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many counterexamples, like $R=\mathbb{Z}$, $I=(2)$, $M=\mathbb{Q}$,    etc

The main fact that you can use to get positive results is

$M$ finitely generated, $IM = M$ implies there exists $i\in I$ such that $im = m$ for all $m\in M$.